# How to automatically remove the file extension in a file name

Tags: file, bash, cut

I am trying to make a script in bash that requires the removal of the the file extension from a file name, like the following

```
original:   something.zip
removed version: something
```

And I was thinking I could use cut for this, but I am worried that a situation could arise where there might be a file name that has more than one period, etc, something similar to the following

```
something.v2.zip
```

having said that, I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations as to what I could do to just remove the last period and the text after it from a line of text/filename? any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 f=file.zip
 echo "${f%.zip}"

 file
```

The '%' is a parameter modifier, it means, delete from the right side of the value of the variable whatever is after the '%' char, in this case, the string `.zip`. You can make this more general to remove any trailing extension, by using a wild card like

```
 echo "${f%.*}"

 file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the from the last period to the end, try this:

```
$ f=some.thing.zip
$ echo "${f%.*}"
some.thing
```

Comment: I lucked out. Keep posting! ;-)

Comment: shellter had beat you by a bit, but thanks for the info though, much appreciated!