# mutiple returns from a function in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix

```
function get_arguments()
{
    read -p 'data : ' data
    read -p 'lambda: ' lambda
    echo $data $lambda 

}


 data,lambda=$(get_arguments)
```

But i am getting an error

```
data :  /home/wolfman/Downloads/data
lambda value: 2
./shell_script.sh: line 25: data,lambda,= /home/wolfman/Downloads/data: No such file or directory
```

But

1) Why is it even evaluating that whether that file exists or not.. its just a string??

2) what am i doing wrong :(

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sh` syntax does not allow that.  But, the variables in the function are global, so you can just invoke the function and `data` and `lambda` will be set in the caller.

functions return an integer value, but they can print arbitrary data which can be read by the caller.  For example, you could do:

```
get_arguments | { read data lambda; echo $data $lambda; }
```

The drawback is that the values are only available in that block.  (The pipe creates a subshell, and the values read by `read` are only valid in that subshell.)

Answer (score 1):

shells don't allow direct assignment to lists of variables, you have manage that with shell string parsing (or possibly other methods). Try

```
data_lambda=$(get_arguments)
data=${data_lambda% *}
#-----------------^^space char
lambda=${data_lambda#* }
#------------------^^space char


$d=123 l=345
$data_lambda=$(echo $d $l)
$echo $data_lambda
123 345
$data=${data_lambda% *}
$lambda=${data_lambda#* }
$echo $data
123
$echo $lambda
345
```

Substituting `$(echo $d $l)` for data_lambda=$(get_arguments)`.

See my write-up on [shell parameter modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337953/how-can-i-automatically-remove-the-file-extension-in-a-file-name/13337988#13337988)

IHTH

Comment: @shelter: Hi.. Are you sure it is this way.. I tried this.. but lamda is what i get in data variable??

Comment: typo, `s/lamba/lamdba/g` now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun here are a couple of other possible methods.

```
read -r data lambda <<< $(get_arguments)
```

or

```
set -- $(get_arguments)
data=$1
lambda=$2
```