# Zip files within the directory without file extensions

Tags: linux

I'm trying to zip all the files within a directory which contains .py files individually. But after zipping the files the output that I'm seeing is `.py.zip` vs just `.zip`

Here's the one liner command that I'm trying to execute.

```
cd scripts/python/
for i in *; do zip $i.zip $i; done
```

Comment: unclear if you want to zip all scripts into one file, or zip them individually. Please update your Q with sample list of files (1-3 should be enough) and what you want as a final result. I'll delete this comment when you do so. Good luck.

Comment: `I really hate this dumb machine, I wish that they would sell it; it never does quite what I want, but only what I tell it. `  Well, if you don't want the full name, strip the extension off before you decide to name it.

Comment: Also, quote your variables to prevent unwanted globbing or word splitting.

Comment: Is there any reason `.py.zip` is undesirable? If the files are later moved or copied elsewhere, it seems having the `".py.zip"` would be much more informative than just `".zip"` (and avoid the need to call `unzip -l` to find out what is in the .zip file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/608639), [Extract file basename without path and extension in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2664740/608639), [How to automatically remove the file extension in a file name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13337953/608639), etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are looking for:

```
for i in *py; do 
    zip "${i%.*}".zip "$i"; 
done
```

## Explanation

`${i%.*}:` This makes use of Bash's built in parameter expansion. Here it tries to match everything after `%`. If it does find a match, it uses everything before the match. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion for more information.